# SAS' MISSOVER for data input in R

Tags: r, read.table

I've got a data file A with 7 columns, no missing values, to which I've unix-`join`ed a data file B that has 28 fields. The result file is C. If no match is found in B, then the output row in C only has 7 columns. If there is a match in B, then the output row in C has 35 columns. I've kicked around `join`'s `-e` option to fill the missings 28 filds, but without success.

What I'm trying to do is duplicate SAS's `MISSOVER` input statement in R. For example the following code works perfectly:

```
 dat <- textConnection('x1,x2,x3,x4
 1,2,"present","present"
 3,4
 5,6')

 df <- read.csv(dat, sep=',' , header=T , 
     colClasses = c("numeric" , "numeric", "character", "character"))

 > df
   x1 x2      x3      x4
 1  1  2 present present
 2  3  4                
 3  5  6
```

But when I try to load my C file, I get the following error (using `TRUE` instead of `T`):

```
 df <- read.table( 'C.tab' , header=T , sep='\t', fill=TRUE,
                   colClasses = c(rep('numeric',7),rep('character',28)))


 Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
   line 1 did not have 35 elements
```

The first line (second row in C, after the header), does indeed have only those 7 fields from A. In SAS I'd use the `MISSOVER` statement to set all those trailing missing fields to some missing value. How can I do that in R? Thanks.

Comment: I can't replicate this, which is made particularly difficult because you haven't supplied an example of a `C.tab` file that creates this error.

Comment: It's customer name & address data.

Comment: A vague description doesn't constitute a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Probably one of those names or addresses has `M'Cusik` or `O'Toole` or somesuch.

Comment: I'd be glad to copy-paste an excerpt of the data, but that's probably not a good idea in this case.

Comment: It doesn't _have_ to be real customer names and addresses... it just has to represent your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fill=TRUE` setting to the parameters of `read.table` (or its derivative cousin `read.csv`) are probably what you are looking for.

```
  df <- read.table(dat, sep=',' , header=T , fill=TRUE,
      colClasses = c("numeric" , "numeric", "character", "character"))
 df
#
  x1 x2      x3      x4
1  1  2 present present
2  3  4                
3  5  6
```

The default for fill is TRUE for `read.csv`, but your error says you used fill=T suggesting that you have an object named `T` in your workspace. The default for read.table is `fill=!blank.lines.skip` and since the default is also  `blank.lines.skip = TRUE`, the usual default for `fill` in `read.table` is FALSE.

Your edited question suggests you have other problems in your character fields. The usual suspects are unmatched quotes or octothorpes(`#`) which are effectively line terminators, so try this instead:

```
df <- read.table( 'C.tab' , header=T , sep='\t', fill=TRUE, 
              quote="",
              comment.char="",
              colClasses = c(rep('numeric',7),rep('character',28)))
```

If you are having difficulty with errors related to varying numbers of items per line, it can be very useful to use `count.fields`. It accepts similar parameters to those used by `read.table`. If you have a large number of input lines it can be useful to wrap the call to `count.fields` in a `table` call:

```
length_tbl <- table( count.fields( 'C.tab' , header=TRUE , sep='\t', 
                                    quote="",
                                    comment.char="")
                     )
```

You can then experiment with different options. Once you know what you are looking for you can also identify the line numbers that are causing problems by wrapping a `which` call around count.fields:

```
bad_lines <- which( count.fields( 'C.tab' , header=TRUE , sep='\t', 
                                    quote="",
                                    comment.char="")
                     != 7  # or whatever is the "correct" length
                     )
```

Comment: They have `fill =T`, which (as I know you do know) is not the same.

Comment: I've put TRUE in the code, same result. I was expecting `fill=TRUE` to do the trick, set `comment.char=""` just in case addresses contained '#'. If the consensus is that fill is the option to use, then it seems like I'm looking for special characters.

Comment: The "special characters" to worry about are `'`, `"`, and `#`. Look at the count.fields function to get a handle on that. I find that `table(count.fields(...))` is a compact way of determining the effect of various combinations of read-parameters.

Comment: @DWin You could put `count.fields` suggestion into your answer.